# Occasional unhandled exception with atoi(string.c_str()) Updated

Tags: c++, c, exception, atoi

UPDATE

I thought stoi(string) solved it, but it only worked for a little while.
I have added the code for splitString and decrypt below.

I occasionally get unhandled exceptions with atoi() using the supposable same value.

My code looks like this:

```
ifstream myfile ("Save.sav");
string line = "";
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
        getline (myfile,line);

    }
    myfile.close();

    line = StaticFunctions::decrypt(line);

}
vector<string> splitString = StaticFunctions::splitString(line, 's');
return atoi(splitString[0].c_str());
```

So what it does is reading a savefile, then it decrypts it and then it splits the string by every 's'. When I'm debugging, the savefile is always the same and the first value is 3.

This work sometimes, maybe every 10 attempt. So every 9 out of 10 attempts I get unhandled exception at  ... at memory location.

Monitoring the converted value shows it always returns 3 and then the application doesn't crash until I start the game which is a bit further in the code.

If I remove the atoi and just return 3 the application works fine.

I've tried strtod but it didn't help.

Thanks,

- Markus

SplitString code:

```
 vector<string> StaticFunctions::splitString(string str, char splitByThis)
 {
vector<string> tempVector;
unsigned int pos = str.find(splitByThis);
unsigned int initialPos = 0;

// Decompose statement
while( pos != std::string::npos ) {
    tempVector.push_back(str.substr( initialPos, pos - initialPos + 1 ) );
    initialPos = pos + 1;

    pos = str.find(splitByThis, initialPos );
}

// Add the last one
tempVector.push_back(str.substr(initialPos, std::min(pos, str.size()) - initialPos + 1));

return tempVector;
```

}

Decrypt code (very simple):

```
string StaticFunctions::decrypt(string decryptThis)
{
for(int x = 0; x < decryptThis.length(); x++)
{
    switch(decryptThis[x])
    {
        case  '*':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '0';
            break;
        }
        case  '?':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '1';
            break;
        }
        case  '!':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '2';
            break;
        }
        case  '=':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '3';
            break;
        }
        case  '#':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '4';
            break;
        }
        case  '^':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '5';
            break;
        }
        case  '%':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '6';
            break;
        }
        case  '+':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '7';
            break;
        }
        case  '-':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '8';
            break;
        }
        case  '"':
        {
            decryptThis[x] = '9';
            break;
        }
    }
}
return decryptThis;
}
```

Comment: Not that it has any relation with your problem, but there is no need to initialise `line` with `string line = "";`; just `string line;` will create an empty string.

Comment: Can you post definition of `StaticFunctions::splitString()`?

Comment: how are `StaticFunctions::splitString` and `StaticFunctions::decrypt` implemented? Maybe they mess up the strings you are later processing with `atoi`?

Comment: Try std::stoi (C++11, works with `std::string` instead of `const char*`). If you mess up the strings, it will throw either `invalid argument` (if the string can't be converted to an integer) or `out_of_range` (if the integer represented by the string is too large). At least you will know what's wrong.

Comment: Don't use the `good` function to check for looping, instead do e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, using stoi with a string instead of atoi and const *char solved it.

Comment: I'm afraid stoi(string) didn't solve it, it only worked for a while.

Comment: Can you do a printf("->%s<- %ld\n",splitString[0].c_str(),strlen(splitString[0].c_str())); and see what it produces?

Comment: it prints:->3s<- 2 no matter if the application crashes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try use strtol instead

strtol (splitString[0].c_str(),NULL,10);

Answer (score 0):

stoi(string) instead of atoi(string.c_str()) solved it.

UPDATE:
It did not solve it.